# Pickle-loading more than 1 line of pkl model file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, pickle

File in question has lines like this when opened with Notepad++:

```
€X   Neural Networksq .€]q (X   ClassificationqKX      Team1 winq]q(X   Team1qX   Team2qe]q(X
Team1_rankqX
Team2_rankqX   Diff1q   X   Diff2q
e}q(hcpandas.core.indexes.base
_new_Index
qcpandas.core.indexes.base
Index
q
```

etc. There are a lot of symbols that aren't shown above in the pkl file.

Below are the codes I've tried to read/parse the file into something readable:

With pickle:

```
import pickle; pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL
with open(r"somefile.pkl", 'rb') as f:
data = pickle.load(f)
print (data)
```

With pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
up_df = pd.read_pickle(r"somefile.pkl")
print (up_df)
```

In both cases, I get a `str` object that only writes 'Neural Network'

My `somefile.pkl` is 63kb in size and obviously has bytecode? (guessing it is) in it. How do I go about converting it to something readable?

Comment: Maybe your pkl file is corrputed?

Comment: @FarhoodET It's working as intended when fed into an `.exe`, so that's unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the pickle file has multiple objects appended to it. Try something like -

```
objects = []
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
data = pickle.load(f)
    while True:
        try:
            objects.append(pickle.load(filename))
        except EOFError:
            break
```

Refer to [How to read pickle file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067957/how-to-read-pickle-file)