# Why does pickle only reads the first line of the file?

Tags: python, pickle

I made a program that stores some data into a file with Pickle

Here is what the file looks like:

```
ÄX
(7836)q.ÄX
(13289)q.ÄX
(0928)q.ÄX
(26)q.ÄX
(7893)q.ÄX
(3883)q.ÄX
(1982)q.ÄX
```

what it is is not important

but when I try to read it with:

```
data = pickle.load(open("num.txt", "rb"))
print(data)
```

this is the output:

```
(7836)
```

while the expected result is:

```
(7836)
(13289)
(0928)
(26)
(7893)
(3883)
(1982)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your expected result doesn't make any sense, it isn't a valid python literal. What, **exactly** were you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting it to print what i dumped, in the case, what you see up there

Comment: Right, that **doesn't make any sense**. What object, **exactly**, do you expect `data` to be?

Comment: `pickle.load()` expects a pickle format file— created with `pickle.dump()` — but it looks like you may be trying to give it a text file. How was the `num.txt` file created?

Comment: ```txt_filename = (str(imagename)+'.txt')
save = open(txt_filename, "wb")```like this

Comment: then I added data like this:
```pickle.dump(str(number), save)```

Comment: @martineau the problem is that the OP is showing the pickle file opened in some text editor which is being decoded from the raw bytes.

Comment: Note, you can call `pickle.load` multiple times on your file to get multiple objects out of it. Or store your objects in a container, then serialize the container. But again, your expected output doesn't make any sense, although you likely want one of those two alternatives

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Yes, I thought that might be the case — and is why I asked how it was created. That would also tell us what to expect `load()` to return.

Comment: what would be a better way for me to store and reacces data then?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067957/how-to-read-pickle-file).
I tried only @jsbueno's answer so far, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following is @jsbueno's answer, worked for me.To be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067957/how-to-read-pickle-file) +more answers.

Pickle serializes a single object at a time, and reads back a single object - the pickled data is recorded in sequence on the file.

If you simply do pickle.load you should be reading the first object serialized into the file (not the last one as you've written).

After unserializing the first object, the file-pointer is at the beggining of the next object - if you simply call pickle.load again, it will read that next object - do that until the end of the file.

```
objects = []
with (open("myfile", "rb")) as openfile:
    while True:
        try:
            objects.append(pickle.load(openfile))
        except EOFError:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'll explain this , it is simple, the file is:

```
    ÄX
    (7836)q.ÄX
    (13289)q.ÄX
    (0928)q.ÄX
    (26)q.ÄX
    (7893)q.ÄX
    (3883)q.ÄX
    (1982)q.ÄX
```

When u give

```
    print(pickle.load(File1))
```

The output is:

```
    (7836)
```

But when you give

```
    print(pickle.load(File1))
    print(pickle.load(File1))
    print(pickle.load(File1))
```

The output is:

```
    (7836)
    (13289)
    (0928)
```

So the thing is pickle.load reads only one line at a time so what i suggest is that u find the number of lines of the file, simply by splitting at the '.' just like i've given below and loading line by line using for loop

```
    f1=open("File1.dat")

    file_contents=str(f1.read())
    list_of_records=file_contents.split('.')
    no_of_records=len(list_of_records)-1

    f1.seek(0)
    for i in range(no_of_records):
    print(pickle.load(f1))
```