# Python json of a list

Tags: python, json, list

I have a list of objects I defined.

At this moment I am iterating over every element in this list and dumping it into a file. But when I want to recreate the objects I run into problems:

```
f = open(path, 'w')
for element in ListOfElements:
    json.dump(element.__dict__, f)
f.close()
```

When trying to recreate an object I do the following:

```
a = json.JSONDecoder(object_hook = Element.from_json).decode(f.read())
```

But this is very bad as I must introduce some kind of splitters between the objects in the file. Then it would not be a "true" json anymore.
Is there a way to make some kind of

```
json.dump(ListOfElements, f) #this exact code gives me "... is not JSON serializable"
```

which would then create a file that is able of recreating the entire list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing objects use python in built **pickle or cPickle** module. These are created specially for storing object.

Check this example from

```
import pickle

a = {'hello': 'world'}

with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
  pickle.dump(a, handle)

with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
  b = pickle.load(handle)

print a == b
```

from [How can I use pickle to save a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218477/how-can-i-use-pickle-to-save-a-dict)