# How can I write an array to a .txt file, and then fill an array with the same.txt file?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, text-files

So I'm doing a ToDo app, and I need to save an array of sentences and words to a .txt file. I have done some research but haven't found any tutorials that explain it well enough so I could understand it. As I said I'm using Python 3. Code below:

```
# Command line TO-DO list
userInput = None
userInput2 = None
userInput3 = None
todo = []
programIsRunning = True

print("Welcome to the TODO list made by Alex Chadwick. Have in mind 
that closing the program will result in your TODO"
  " list to DISAPPEAR. We are working on correcting that.")
print("Available commands: add (will add item to your list); remove 
(will remove item from your list); viewTODO (will"
      " show you your TODO list); close (will close the app")

with open('TODOList.txt', 'r+') as f:
    while programIsRunning == True:
        print("Type in your command: ")
        userInput = input("")

        if userInput == "add":
            print("Enter your item")
            userInput2 = input("")
            todo.append(userInput2)
            continue

        elif userInput == "viewTODO":
            print(todo)
            continue

        elif userInput == "remove":
            print(todo)
            userInput3 = input("")
            userInput3 = int(userInput3)
            userInput3 -= 1
            del todo[userInput3]
            continue

        elif userInput == "close":
            print("Closing TODO list")
            programIsRunning = False
            continue

        else:
            print("That is not a valid command")
```

Comment: `programIsRunning == False`  is a comparison, not a assignment. You probably want to assignt `False` to your variable so fix it to `programIsRunning = False`. Youd be better off to 1) read your data into a list structure at the start ... 2) manipulate the list to add/remove todos ... 3) save your list to a file again on close.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218477/how-can-i-use-pickle-to-save-a-dict) discusses how to save a dictionary. Saving a list is just the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `pickle`!

Pickle is a built-in module for saving objects and data in Python. To use it, you will need to put `import pickle` at the top of your program.

To save to a file:

```
file_Name = "testfile.save" #can be whatever you want
# open the file for writing
fileObject = open(file_Name,'wb') 

# this writes the object to the file
pickle.dump(THING_TO_SAVE,fileObject)   

# here we close the fileObject
fileObject.close()
```

To load from a file:

```
# we open the file for reading
fileObject = open(file_Name,'r')  
# load the object from the file
LOADED_THING= pickle.load(fileObject)  
fileObject.close()
```

The code in this answer was taken from [here.](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/02/what-is-pickle-in-python/)

I hope that helps!

Comment: do I have to include the extension in the {testfile.save}?

Comment: @AlexChadwick you can have files with or without an extension, just make sure that you load them with the same exact name, including extension. The extension can be anything, not just `.save`.

Comment: Do I have to change THING_TO_SAVE for the name of the array?

Answer (score 0):

You use a simple text file to store your TODO - items and retrieve them from it:

```
import sys
fn = "todo.txt"

def fileExists():
    """https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-fi
    answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/82852/7505395
    """
    import os

    return os.path.isfile(fn) 

def saveFile(todos):
    """Saves your file to disk. One line per todo"""
    with open(fn,"w") as f: # will overwrite existent file
        for t in todos:
            f.write(t)
            f.write("\n")

def loadFile():
    """Loads file from disk. yields each line."""
    if not fileExists():
        raise StopIteration
    with open(fn,"r") as f:
        for t in f.readlines():
            yield t.strip()

def printTodos(todos):
    """Prints todos with numbers before them (1-based)"""
    for i,t in enumerate(todos):
        print(i + 1, t)

def addTodo(todos):
    """Adds a todo to your list"""
    todos.append(input("New todo:"))
    return todos

def deleteTodos(todos):
    """Prints the todos, allows removal by todo-number (as printed)."""
    printTodos(todos)
    i = input("Which number to delete?")
    if i.isdigit() and 0 < int(i) <= len(todos): #  1 based
        r = todos.pop(int(i) - 1)
        print("Deleted: ", r)
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
    return todos

def quit():
    i = input("Quitting without saving [Yes] ?").lower()
    if i == "yes":
        exit(0) # this exits the while True: from menu()

def menu():
    """Main loop for program. Prints menu and calls subroutines based on user input."""

    # sets up all available commands and the functions they call, used
    # for printing commands and deciding what to do
    commands = {"quit": quit, "save" : saveFile, "load" : loadFile, 
                "print" : printTodos, 
                "add": addTodo, "delete" : deleteTodos}
    # holds the loaded/added todos
    todos = []
    inp = ""
    while True:
        print("Commands:", ', '.join(commands)) 
        inp = input().lower().strip()
        if inp not in commands:
            print("Invalid command.")
            continue
        # some commands need params or return smth, they are handled below
        if inp == "load":
            try:
                todos = [x for x in commands[inp]() if x] # create list, no ""
            except StopIteration:
                # file does not exist...
                todos = []
        elif inp in [ "save","print"]:
            if todos:
                commands[inp](todos) # call function and pass todos to it
            else:
                print("No todos to",inp) # print noting to do message

        elif inp in ["add", "delete"]:
            todos = commands[inp](todos) # functions with return values get 
                                         # todos passed and result overwrites 
                                         # it 
        else: # quit and print are handled here
            commands[inp]()

def main():
    menu()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(int(main() or 0))
```