# Writing dictionary of dataframes to a single file

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, dictionary

Trying to capture multiple years of daily updated 2-D tables.  I can download them to a dictionary of dataframes.  Trying to write it to a CSV file, so I do not have to download it every time.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd 

def saver(dictex):
    for key, val in dictex.items():
        val.to_csv("data_{}.csv".format(str(key)))

    with open("keys.txt", "w") as f: #saving keys to file
        f.write(str(list(dictex.keys()))

def loader():
    """Reading data from keys"""
    with open("keys.txt", "r") as f:
        keys = eval(f.read())
    dictex = {}    
    for key in keys:
        dictex[key] = pd.read_csv("data_{}.csv".format(str(key)))

    return dictex

dictex = loader()
```

It can save all the keys and values in different files.  My next step is to put all the data in one file.

I tried the following method, but it seems to only work with 1d dictionary.  As it cannot read back with the following error message.

"ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 0; 2 is required"

```
with open('datadict.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in data.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
with open('datadict.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    mydict = dict(reader)
```

Here is a hand-made data set similar to what I am working with.  I would like to wirte dictdf to a csv and read it back with the same structure.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4),
index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

dates2 = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4),
index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

dictdf={}
dictdf['xxset']=df1
dictdf['yyset']=df2
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Do you want all the csv's joined in 1 big dataframe? Is the structure (# and names of columns) identical in all csv's?

Comment: No, not a big data frame, I would like to put them in a big dictionary of dataframes, if possible.  Their names and columns are the same.  It looks fine in data[date] before I write it in.

Comment: What is `data[date]` in your code? I don't see any `data` object.

Comment: The value is a 957x16 dataframe each day using date as the key.  I am trying to using two days of data to test it.

Comment: So `data` is the same as your `dictex` variable in the code above?

Comment: import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4),
    index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

    dates2 = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4),
    index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

    dictdf={}
    dictdf['xxset']=df1
    dictdf['yyset']=df2

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the exact structure of your keys.txt is or your csv's, but based on your code, I'd suspect something like this to join all csv's into one DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

"""Reading data from keys"""
with open("keys.txt", "r") as f:
    keys = eval(f.read())
list_of_dfs = []

# Read in all csv files and append to list
for key in keys:
    list_of_dfs.append(pd.read_csv("data_{}.csv".format(str(key)))) # based on your example

# Join all dataframes into 1 big one
big_df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs)
```

## EDIT

If you want to save the dictionary **with** the dataframes to 1 file, saving it as a pickle file might be a better option. 
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218477/how-can-i-use-pickle-to-save-a-dict) .

Comment: The intention was to put a dictionary of dataframes into a CSV file.  And I would like to read it back with the same data structure so I can continue the operation later on.  I have added a sample data set for testing.

Comment: So you want to write the dictionary WITH the data from the dataframe's into 1 csv-file? That is not possible. A dictionary with dataframe's as values doesn't match the 2D format of a csv-file. If you really want to keep the dictionary format with underlying dataframe's, saving it as a pickle file might be a better way.

Comment: Thanks.  Save it as a pickle file is an alternative.