# Saving cookies to file and reusing in selenium web driver python -- Encoding list object

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to read cookies from a session and save it in a file(I'm saving it as python pickle file) and use it next time rather than logging into the application again. It saves a lot of time. I'm using  Python 2.7.16rc1 and selenium web driver version 3.14.1.

I have tried saving the cookie  which I get from `driver.get_cookies()`. The issue is that the cookies are saved in the pickled object with Unicode encoding with `u in it which is causing the issue while reading it and sending it back.

I have tried to deal with the Unicode encoding option by reading the value in list one by one and applying UTF-8 encoding but getting a `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'`

The given below is the code to write the cookies to a pickle file

`pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookie.fkle","w"))`

The below codes reads it

```
import pickle

cookies = pickle.load(open("cookie.fkle", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    print cookie
```

I expect the output as below

```
{domain': google.com', name': lang', value': en', expiry': 1555427577, path': /', httpOnly': False, secure': False}
{domain': .google.com', name': _ga', value': GA1.2.1834438095.1554822783', expiry': 1617894782, path': /', httpOnly': False, secure': False}
{domain': .google.com', name': _gid', value': GA1.2.1839091575.1554822783', expiry': 1554909182, path': /', httpOnly': False, secure': False}
{domain': .google.com', name': _gat_gtag_UA_60214108_5', value': 1', expiry': 1554822842, path': /', httpOnly': False, secure': False}
```

But I'm getting the output as:

```
{u'domain': u'google.com', u'name': u'lang', u'value': u'en', u'expiry': 1555427577, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'secure': False}
{u'domain': u'.google.com', u'name': u'_ga', u'value': u'GA1.2.1834438095.1554822783', u'expiry': 1617894782, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'secure': False}
{u'domain': u'.google.com', u'name': u'_gid', u'value': u'GA1.2.1839091575.1554822783', u'expiry': 1554909182, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'secure': False}
{u'domain': u'.google.com', u'name': u'_gat_gtag_UA_60214108_5', u'value': u'1', u'expiry': 1554822842, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'secure': False}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply encode or decode a dictionary, you need to iterate over each key and value and replace them by encoded ones.
Also for dumping, you need to open the file in binary mode and there is a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218477/how-can-i-use-pickle-to-save-a-dict):

`pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookie.fkle","wb"))`

Easy way in here is to just encode each line (represents as a dictionary) within a function. Something like this:

```
import pickle

def encode_dict(input_dict):
    output = {}
    for key in input_dict:
        output.update({key.encode('utf-8'): input_dict[key].encode('utf-8')})
    return output

cookies = pickle.load(open("cookie.fkle", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    print encode_dict(cookie)
```

Answer (score 0):

M.R

Thanks alot

However I tweaked the answer a bit

`output.update({str(key).encode('utf-8'): str(input_dict[key]).encode('utf-8')})` as I was getting a AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode' python dictionary