# Caching Database queries between runs in Pycharm

Tags: database, caching, pycharm

I'm debugging code and to debug I need to load database tables. This is the majority of time spent for each run. Is there a way in Pycharm to cache these results so that I can debug faster, rather than reloading the tables every time I refresh the debug?

Answer (score 1):

You can store (a subset of) the data in a [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), or text file and read from that file instead of the database when debugging.

Dependent on what datatype you use to store the database data (you don't provide any code or [a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) you can use different methods to store a pickle file, here are two:

- [pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html)
- [Pickle a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11218477/1256347)

A more complex and general method would be to use a real cache like memcached with your python script. [This article](https://realpython.com/python-memcache-efficient-caching/) describes how.
The article is too comprehensive to reproduce here, so I would recommend to read it there.