# Cannot pickle object: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to pickle objects that I generate in a script to process them afterwards, but I get this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-2-0f716e86ecd3>", line 1, in <module>
pickle.dump(thisperson, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object
```

Here `thisperson` is relatively simple (or so I thought): a name and a dictionary containing attributes:

```
class Attributes:
    def __init__(self, what_attr, attr):
        self._what_attr = what_attr
        self._attributes = attr

    @property
    def what_attr(self):
        return self._what_attr
    @what_attr.setter
    def what_attr(self, new_value):
        self._what_attr = new_value

    @property
    def attributes(self):
        return self._attributes
    @attributes.setter
    def attributes(self, new_value):
        self._attributes = new_value


class Person:
    def __init__(self, watname, watage):
        self._myname = watname
        self._age = watage
        self._attributes = []

    @property
    def attributes(self):
        return self._attributes
    @attributes.setter
    def attributes(self, attributes_list):
        self._attributes = attributes_list

    @property
    def myname(self):
        return self._myname
    @myname.setter
    def myname(self, value):
        self._myname = value

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age
    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        self._age = value
```

the pickle function looks like this:

```
import pickle

def save_person(person, mypath):
    import os
    if not os.path.exists(mypath):
        os.makedirs(mypath)
    my_path = mypath + str(person.myname)
    if not os.path.exists(my_path + '/'):
        os.makedirs(my_path + '/')
    with open(my_path + '.pkl', 'wb') as output:
        pickle.dump(person, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

This error seems to be coming from the fact that the class contains a string and a `dict` because if I keep attributes as an empty `dict` I don't get the error.

Is there another way I can pickle objects like these?

I tried increasing `sys.setrecursionlimit`, but that didn't help.

Edit:
.... I can't reproduce the error if i use a short version of the code .... go figure.
@MinhNguyen something weird is that i create my attributes dict in a function (attr = get_attributes(data)), but when i create the same dict myself, i can pickle it ....

```
thisperson = Person("Kenny", 22, {})
attr = get_attributes(data)  # returns {'eyes': 'blue', 'hair': 'brown'}
this_attr = Attributes(person_name, attr)
this_person.attributes.append(this_attr)
save_person(this_person, main_folder)

Exception ignored in: 
'_pydevd_frame_eval.pydevd_frame_evaluator_win32_37_64.get_bytecode_while_frame_eval'
 RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
 Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

but if I do the following it works:

```
attr = {'eyes': 'blue', 'hair': 'brown'}
this_attr = Attributes(person_name, attr)
this_person.attributes.append(this_attr)
save_person(this_person, main_folder)
```

### Solution

Alright so after further digging, I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218477/how-can-i-use-pickle-to-save-a-dict) that pickle doesn't mingle with dict well and will often crash.

So the workaround was that I dropped the Attribute class completely and now my Person's _attribute is a string of dict ***self._attributes = str(dict())*** and whenever I want to add things to it, I'll do an eval(), update() and str() again.

This seem to be working so far...

Comment: As a side note, you probably want to being using single-underscores for attributes, as in `_name` and `_attributes`, rather that double-underscores. That former is a convention for indicating the an attribute is an implementation detail, while the latter [invokes name mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name).

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: Since pickle complains about recursion depth exceeded, I don't think your dictionary is causing a problem. Can you provide more source codes? Maybe you implement some recursive functions with depth depending on the content of the dictionary?

Comment: @MinhNguyen i edited my post to include more info. I tried checking the attributes dict in terms of memory and types, they are the same whether i use my function or create it manually

Comment: Why are you using `@property` here?  NONE of your attributes benefit from it even slightly - it's for situations where the public attributes don't correspond exactly to the instance variables (there's a side-effect on setting something, there's calculation involved in reading a value, etc.).

Comment: @jasonharper that's True, but even if i take all properties and setters out of the classes definitions, i get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

### Problem

I've been using the `concurrent.futures` module, particularly the `ProcessPoolExecutor` class, which uses (kind of under the hood) `pickle` module to return values to the main process.
The issue with this, is that `pickle` module seems to have a limit on what you can "pickle-ize" when we are talking about nested stuff. In my case, I had a structure like the following:

```
data = [
    {
        "string_list": [
            ["a1", "a2", ..., "an"],
            ["b1", "b2", ..., "bn"],
            ...
            ["n1", "n2", ..., "nn"],
        ]
    },
    {
        "string_list": [
            ["a1", "a2", ..., "an"],
            ["b1", "b2", ..., "bn"],
            ...
            ["n1", "n2", ..., "nn"],
        ]
    },
```

Basically, it was a list of dictionaries, which everyone of them contained, a list of string lists. I mean, it was a relatively nested structure. And every time i tried to get the `data` from the `ProcessPoolExecutor's` result, it raised a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object`, due to pickle module, which can't (apparently) deal with this level of nesting.

### Solution

My solution was similar to the provided in the edited question. I "stringified" the structure before pickling it, and then undone it once I could access the `data`. Personally, I used json module, which also comes with Python Standard Library.

This was my "experience" dealing with the pickle module.

Answer (score 1):

Quick remark: I found that for my object, **IntEnum** caused this. Had one instance of it, replaced it with a bunch of constants, and the exception disappeared.