# Save Interpolation output from Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, pickle

I have a problem where I need to interpolate a 3D function using e.g. SciPy, and then save the output of this interpolation for future use. That is, I don't want to have to run the interpolation procedure every time as generating the 3D function to be interpolated is computationally demanding (it is from the Biot-Savart law so is a lot of numerical integrations).

However, I'm having trouble understanding if this is possible and, secondly, how to implement this. From what I've seen on some other posts, it should be possible, but the solutions don't seem to work for me.

I have written the following test code, but I receive the below error when testing it:

> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

This error is when is on the code line starting `zeroVal` in the function `loadInterpolation()`. I was hoping the `allow_pickle=True` would have solved this, based on what I read previously
.

```
import scipy
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

def f(x,y,z):
    field = -x**2-y**2+z**2
    return field

def performSaveInterpolation():
    print(scipy.__version__)
    print('Performing Interpolation...')
    x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
    y = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
    z = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
    xg, yg ,zg = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij', sparse=True)
    data = f(xg,yg,zg)
    my_interpolating_function = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), data)
    zeroVal = my_interpolating_function([0,0,0])
    oneVal = my_interpolating_function([1,1,1])
    print('Interpolated function @ (0,0,0): ' + str(zeroVal))
    print('Interpolated function @ (1,1,1): ' + str(oneVal))
    np.save('interpolation.npy',my_interpolating_function,allow_pickle=True)
    return 0

def loadInterpolation():
    print('Loading Interpolation...')
    interpolationFunc = np.load('interpolation.npy',allow_pickle=True)
    zeroVal = interpolationFunc([0,0,0])
    oneVal = interpolationFunc([1,1,1])
    print('Interpolated function @ (0,0,0): ' + str(zeroVal))
    print('Interpolated function @ (1,1,1): ' + str(oneVal))
    return 0

performSaveInterpolation()
loadInterpolation()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using pickle directly ? Linked to the question : [How-can-i-use-pickle-to-save-a-dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218477/how-can-i-use-pickle-to-save-a-dict).

Pickle is supposed to be able to serialize **any possible type** of python object. Not only numpy arrays (wich [numpy save](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) function is **only** able to do. It cannot save other objects types than np.arrays, and an iterpolation function is not an `numpy.ndarray` type, hence the errror)

Use it like this :

### TLDR :

```py
import pickle

with open('mypicklefile.pck', 'wb') as file_handle:
    pickle.dump(my_saved_object, file_handle)
```

then :

```py
with open('mypicklefile.pck', 'rb') as file_handle:
    my_loaded_object = pickle.load(file_handle)
```

---

**If you ever need to serialize multiple objects** at once, for example, your function, and `zeroVal` as well as `oneVal` to avoid extracting them from the function every time, you could either :

### Solution 1

Serialize multiple times on the same file :

```py
with open('mypicklefile.pck', 'wb') as file_handle:
    pickle.dump(my_saved_object, file_handle)
    pickle.dump(my_saved_object2, file_handle)
    pickle.dump(my_saved_object3, file_handle)
```

And then deserialize as many times (order matters ! You have to "remember" which object is which)

```py
with open('mypicklefile.pck', 'rb') as file_handle:
    my_loaded_object = pickle.load(file_handle)
    my_loaded_object2 = pickle.load(file_handle)
    my_loaded_object3 = pickle.load(file_handle)
```

### Solution 2

Or, (better solution IMO) use a dictionnary, to have a tiny bit of metadata with each object, in that it has a name (the key) :

```py
mydata = {"tiny_description": my_saved_object, "something_more" : my_saved_object2}

with open('mypicklefile.pck', 'wb') as file_handle:
    pickle.dump(mydata , file_handle)

with open('mypicklefile.pck', 'rb') as file_handle:
    temp_dict = pickle.load(file_handle)
    tiny_description = temp_dict["tiny_description"]
    something_more = emp_dict["something_more"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! I'm sure something like this is the solution. 

However, I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I've not used the pickle functionality before. In your example, how do I save the output of the interpolation (e.g. my_interpolating_function) which in this case is the object to be saved and then reloaded later? 

I can only seem how to open it from what you've written.

Comment: @classAction68 In python, **everything** is an object. So with dump, you have your object `my_interpolated_function` serialized and written in the file wich you opened previously, with a handle to this file as an object (`file_handle`). Then, when you open it again, with another handle to read the file (same name for second the handle in my example) you use load, wich **takes as argument** the handle and returns as object the deserialized object that was contained inside the file. thus, in my example : `my_loaded_object` is (theoretically) **exactly**  the same as `my_interpolated_function`.

Comment: Names of objects don't matter. Only content do. For example you could do : ``import numpy as np`` then ``foo = np`` and finally ``bar = foo.array([1,2,3])`` it would yeild a ``numpy.ndarray`` exactly like using np, because foo **is** np.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I realise now that the 'pickle.dump' is the thing that is saving it to my disk - it was the object was being saved to disk that I didn't understand previously

Comment: Yes, exactly. No worries. Have a good coding journey !

Comment: @classAction68 You can accept the answer if it solved your issue, so that is appears having a solution. Which is usefull both for people who seek an answer, and for people that are scanning burried unanswered questions to "clean" stack overflow.

Comment: Done. Thank you.