# NetworkX - How to reproduce the drawing shape

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

MDG = nx.MultiDiGraph()

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Forward edges
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
forward_edges = [
    ("sushi/0", "goes/1"), 
    ("sushi/0", "with/2"), 
    ("sushi/0", "wasabi/3"), 
    ("goes/1", "with/2"),
    ("goes/1", "wasabi/3"),
    ("with/2", "wasabi/3"),
]
MDG.add_edges_from(
    forward_edges,
    edge_color='b',
    weight='length',
    length=100,
)

# layout definition must come after adding all nodes/edges. 
# Otherwise Node X has no position error.
pos=nx.spring_layout(MDG, weight='length')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Draw nodes & labels
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(
    MDG, 
    pos, 
    ax=ax,
    node_size=500,
    node_color="cyan",
)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(
    MDG, 
    pos, 
    ax=ax,
    font_weight='bold',
    font_size=12,
)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Draw forward edges
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
nx.draw_networkx_edges(
    MDG, 
    pos, 
    ax=ax, 
    edgelist=forward_edges, 
    edge_color="b",
    arrowsize=20,
    arrowstyle="->",
#    connectionstyle='arc3, rad=0.25',
)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(
    MDG, 
    pos,
    label_pos=0.2,
    edge_labels={
        ("sushi/0", "goes/1"): 0.3, 
        ("sushi/0", "with/2"): 0.1, 
        ("sushi/0", "wasabi/3"): 0.6, 
        ("goes/1", "with/2"): 0.75,
        ("goes/1", "wasabi/3"): 0.75,
        ("with/2", "wasabi/3"): 0.75,
    },
    font_color='b'
)
nx.set_edge_attributes(
    G=MDG,
    values={
        ("sushi/0", "goes/1", 0.1): {"label": 0.1},
        ("sushi/0", "with/2", 0.1): {"label": 0.2},
        ("sushi/0", "wasabi/3", 0.6): {"label": 0.6},
        ("goes/1", "with/2", 0.1): {"label": 0.1},
        ("goes/1", "wasabi/3", 0.75): {"label": 0.75},
        ("with/2", "wasabi/3", 0.75): {"label": 0.75},
    }
)
```

[image]

However, next time run the same code the shape is different.

[image]

## Question

Is there a way to consistently reproduce the first shape? Apparently the `seed` parameter is the one to use. However, how can we get the value to set to `seed` parameter to consistently reproduce the first figure?

I suppose after the first figure is generated, need to find out the `seed` value actually used, then reuse it. But not sure how.

Comment: If you only care about the shape you can store the `pos` only from the first run and keep using the same positions when drawing the other graphs (assuming the node labels are always the same). I'm not quite sure if I got your question right though, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned from `nx.spring_layout` is a `dict` you can save and re-use (or even modify) once you have a layout you want to keep. If you print it, you'll see it's a dictionary of numpy arrays that store the position of each node.

```
pos = {'sushi/0': array([0.20632381, 0.0243153]),
       'goes/1': array([0.59708043, 0.2527625]),
       'with/2': array([0.19659576, 0.52970947]),
       'wasabi/3': array([-1., -0.80678727])}
```

If you want to keep using the exact same node positions between runs of your program, you could [pickle that dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11218477/1288) and load it in place of calling `nx.spring_layout`. (Or for a small example like this, you could hard code it.)